# Proper way to do a pointer-to-string in a qsort function

Tags: c

Let's say I have an array of strings I want to sort, such as:

```
{"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

Using `qsort` what would be the proper cast operation when passing those strings?

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    // string1 = ???   
};
```

My thought is the item would be a "pointer-to-string", and since a string is a "pointer-to-char", this would give me a "pointer-to-pointer-char". Is the following the correct way to do this?

```
// 1. Pointer-to String
(String) *

// 2. String = Pointer-to-char
(char*) *

// 3. What about const-ness? Doesn't qsort require the 'value' to be const? 
//    Also, what about string = unsigned char -- is that important here?
(const char*) *
```

So, would the proper definition of `string1` be:

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char* string1 = (const char**) p1;
};
```

Is the the correct way to do it? You can see how tedious (for me at least) it is to figure out what the pointer declarations (or cast in this case) is. Is there a more straightforward way to do it -- that is, a way where if I know I want a "pointer-to-string" I can do it (in the proper way, with `const` and `unsigned` or whatever) in less than five minutes?

Comment: There's no such thing as "pointer to string", it's just "pointer to char" with the expectation that the destination is a series of non-NUL bytes, followed by a NUL byte at the end. If you're sorting a list of `char*`, the type is `char*`. If casting is required from `void*`, you cast back to `char*`.

Comment: @tadman right -- does the second code block clarify that point though? I just mean conceptually I think `string` and I write in `char*`.

Comment: My advice: **Don't** think `string`, that doesn't exist in C. It shouldn't exist in C. Any `typedef` to make it exist is only going to make a mess of things, as you'll then think `string` is a type you can do `sizeof` on, which is wrong. It's important to be explicit that it is `char*`, that it is in fact a pointer to `char`. The value should be cast from `void*` to `char*` where you can `const` if you prefer.

Comment: @tadman: That's just not correct. The argument to the comparison function is a pointer to a constant pointer to char, cast to a pointer to const void.

Comment: @tadman I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: David542, In C, _string_ is a "contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".  String exists.  Not as a type, but as a description of data meeting a criteria.  So a "pointer to a string" exist, but that is descriptive of the data.  Much like there are no "pointer to odd", yet we can have a `int *` pointing to a `7` as well as an `unsigned *` pointing to a `7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qsort` provides the comparison function with two const pointers to the elements of the array begin sorted. You're sorting an array of "strings", which is to say an array of `char*`. An array of `char*` is `char*[]`, a pointer to an element in such an array is a pointer to `char*`, which would be `char**`, and a const pointer to an element in that array would be `char*const*`.

You'll probably end up using `strcmp` to compare the two strings, or something similar. If it were `strcmp` itself, you would end up with:

```
int scmp(void const* va, void const* vb) {
  const char* a = *(char* const*)va;
  const char* b = *(char* const*)vb;
  return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

I added unnecessary but harmless `const` qualifiers to `a` and `b`, because `strcmp` doesn't mutate its arguments. Other than that, the example code is pretty well the same as what you would find if you looked at the example code in [man qsort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html#EXAMPLES)

Comment: thanks, could you explain why we want a "const pointer" to an element and not a pointer to a "const element", or even "const pointer to const element" ? (the other answer uses `const char**`)

Comment: @David542: "the other answer" is casting away `const`; the arguments given to the comparator function are `const void*`, that is to say pointer to immutable objects of an unspecified type. We now want to specify the type, which is `char*`. So we need a pointer to an immutable object of type `char *`. That's `char* const*`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Is that the same thing as `const char* const*`, or is the `const char` part meaningless?

Comment: @David542: I would have declared `list` as `const char* list[] = ...`, because I prefer to be explicit about immutable pointers, and string literals are pointers to immutable objects. Moreover, the prototype of `strcmp` uses `const char*` because it doesn't attempt to mutate the arguments. So I used `const char* const*`, because that's my habit (and I learned C before C89, fwiw :-) ). But the extra `const` isn't really necessary.

Comment: gcc won't complain about @tadman's code unless you ask for that warning, using `-Wcast-qual`. That's because lots of programmers routinely leave out `const`, and the C language lets you do that (as long as you don't try to mutate immutable objects). But IMHO correct consting is a good habit, and the habit will be particularly helpful when you want to use C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of messy because of how `qsort()` uses *pointers to elements*, so if the elements themselves are pointers then you need to somehow convert `void*` into `char*` but also de-reference it one step along the way.

Here's an example of how you'd write such a function:

```c
int qs_strcmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
  return strcmp(*((const char**) a), *((const char**) b));
}
```

And a test program to show how it works:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
  char *list[] = {
    "boba",
    "dada",
    "zapa",
    "cobb",
    "acdc",
    "abba"
  };

  int list_len = sizeof(list) / sizeof(char*);

  qsort(&list[0], list_len, sizeof(char*), qs_strcmp);

  for (int i = 0; i < list_len; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", list[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. It seems like you're using `(const char**)` for the cast and @rici is using `(char* const*)`. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You can treat the target of the pointer and/or the pointer itself as `const`. rici is taking a const pointer approach. I'm probably doing this a more informal way, but I learned C89 when it was the current standard, so I'm going with that excuse.